# After run command 'where.exe flutter dart' received doubled path for sdk, does it mean there are two sdk on my machine?

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk

when I run 'where.exe flutter dart" received this long file?

```
C:\Users\Jake>where.exe flutter dart
C:\source\flutter\bin\flutter
C:\source\flutter\bin\flutter.bat
C:\tools\flutter\bin\flutter
C:\tools\flutter\bin\flutter.bat
C:\source\flutter\bin\dart
C:\source\flutter\bin\dart.bat
C:\Program Files\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe
C:\tools\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe
C:\tools\flutter\bin\dart
C:\tools\flutter\bin\dart.bat
```

Comment: You have the Flutter SDK installed in `C:\source` and in `C:\tools`, and you have the Dart SDK installed in `C:\tools` and in `C:\Program Files`.  If none of them are symlinks to other location, then you have two separate installations.  Note that the Flutter SDK also includes the Dart SDK.

Comment: Having multiple installations is asking for confusion later.  Which one you keep is up to you.